# Angularjs: Watch object and compare to original object

Tags: angularjs

I have a vm with two objects in it:

```
vm.obj = {
    intObj1: {
       title: 'title1'
    },
    intObj2: {
       name: 'name1'
    }
}
```

The vm.obj is bound to the view (I am using the controller as syntax)

I want to have the original data so I cloned the model using lodash:

```
var originalModelState = _.cloneDeep(vm.obj);
```

I am watching for changes in the model compared to the original state:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.obj', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== originalModelState){

        }
    }, true);
```

Sadly `newValue !== originalModelState` is always different, which is expected as the references are different. I tried also comparing `newValue` with `oldValue` but the issue there is that if the user changes a property for example: `vm.obj.intObj1.title = 'new title'` and then change back to the original value `vm.obj.intObj1.title = 'title1' I cannot detect that the vm is the same as the original value. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered

```
var originalModelState = JSON.stringify(vm.obj);
```

...

```
if (JSON.stringify(newValue) != originalModelState){
}
```

Comparing objects as strings is imho a very effective and easy way to spot differences, especially when you not know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood correctly what you wanted to ask. The watcher callback is only executed, if something in your object has changed. The 'true' performs a deep watch.

If you only want to know, if the value deep in your object is equal to the originial value on the same position, you could check in the watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.obj', function(newValue){
  if (originalModelState.intObj1.title === newValue.intObj1.title) {
    // do something
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: this will only detect changes from the last object state but not from the original object